# Can you use a python encryption script from a Visual C# Application?

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, encryption

I want to make a basic encryption/decryption program in Visual C# using a python script. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) is the way to mix C# and Python.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to call Python from C# by using IronPython an example can be found [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/berniea/archive/2008/12/04/extending-your-c-application-with-ironpython.aspx).